# Why doesn't re.sub work in this python2 case?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import re
text = "PO 00000  Frm 00001  Fmt 0624  Sfmt 0634  E:\CR\FM\A07JN6.000  S07JNPT1"
text = re.sub(text, " ", text)

print(text)
```

I'm on Python 2.7.15. The output is `PO 00000  Frm 00001  Fmt 0624  Sfmt 0634  E:\CR\FM\A07JN6.000  S07JNPT1`. Why doesn't the output become `" "`?

Comment: Because the string is not a valid pattern for itself. Why are you using regex for this?

Comment: I get the same result if I seek a partial version of the string. `text = re.sub(text[0:65], " ", text)`. It is part of a larger function that requires regex.

Comment: You can escape them using re.escape ... to look for eactly that _text_

Comment: The first 65 characters also includes the bad escapes. Try using `re.escape`. Note this would be an error in more recent versions of Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `re.escape`

**Ex:**

```
import re
text = "PO 00000  Frm 00001  Fmt 0624  Sfmt 0634  E:\CR\FM\A07JN6.000  S07JNPT1"
text = re.sub(re.escape(text), " ", text)

print(text)
```

Note: You can also use `str.replace` for this case.